# automatic submit data form url by jsp

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine

I tried to use jsp to automatically get input from url and save it to the datastore using a servlet,
here's my code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<html>
<body>
<h1> Testing input from url</h1>
</br>
<ul>
<li><p><b>user:</b>
<%= request.getParameter("user")%>
</p></li>
<li><p><b>content:</b>
<%= request.getParameter("content")%>
</p></li>
<li><p><b>date:</b>
<%= request.getParameter("date")%>
</p></li>
</ul>
<form action="/add" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="%= request.getParameter("user")%"/>
<input type="hidden" name="content" value="%= request.getParameter("content")%"/>
<input type="submit" value="Post value" />
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="${fn:escapeXml(date)}"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

when I tested the code by inserting the value from url like www.myweb?user=me&content=this , it displayed the value but didn't submit to the datastore.
am I doing some mistake here?
thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't u directly submit to the "add" ?

Comment: The syntax highlighting points out that the double quotes in the getParameter("user") and getParameter("content") methods interfere with the double quotes after the value= attributes on the same lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your flow is not clear over here.

I am assuming that you have a Servlet hosted at `/add`, which is responsible for reading the request variables like `user`, `content` and `date` and adding them to the database.

The JSP file that you have provided over here seems a bit out of place.

I would suggest that you have a JSP file like the one above say `add.jsp` that does not have hidden variables. In that case you can populate the form via the browser.

If you want to provide the values automatically like add.jsp?user=me&content=this, that is fine too but then note that **you need to submit the form** to the Servlet mapped to `/add` and hence you should check that Servlet for the database functionality and why it is not adding it to the datastore.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem in hidden fields' values. It's missing angular bracket `<...>`. And the action is starting from `/`. If you are calling the the servlet within the same application you don't need to start the `action` value with `/`

```
   <form action="add" method="get">
      <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<%= request.getParameter("user")%>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="content" value="<%= request.getParameter("content")%>"/>
    .....
    </form>
```